# как сделать что бы пользователь вводил числа, и считалась их сумма c#

Tags: c#

То есть пользователь вводит числа(к примеру 1234), а ему выводит сумму (10)
Но если вводит буквы что бы писало ошибку, к примеру (Please enter only numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();

int num = 0;

foreach (char c in str)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter only numbers");
        return;
    }

    num += int.Parse(c.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Или так

```
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int num))
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        sum += num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter only numbers");
}
```

Comment: Очень странное решение, потому что `int.Parse` может принимать `string`. А исключения можно обрабатывать с помощью `try-catch`. Ну и самое простое решение я добавил в ответ.

Comment: @aepot только там посимвольная сумма нужна

Comment: Возможно, но автор говорит про числа, а не по цифры, думаете перепутал?

Comment: @aepot Возможно, 1234->10 таки в вопросе

Comment: 1 2 3 4 - тоже 10, ок ща допишу

Comment: Даже так можно `for (; num > 0; num /= 10) sum += num % 10;` :)